# XHTML - All markup in one sample page?

Tags: html, xhtml

I'm looking for a simple xhtml page sample where all markups are used. I will use it to test different CSS reset. Where can I find one? Also what it is called? Spent time googling it but no luck. Please, I'm not looking for a tutorial.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Might help to come up with lateral solutions.

Comment: @Blowski I will use it to test different CSS reset.

Comment: You need to define which version of XHTML should be covered. Then you probably need to construct the document yourself, but it should not take long, something like 20 minutes, using just the relevant W3C XHTML specification. But beware that all the browser default renderings might not be tested as they may depend on specific combinations of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the list available here...

http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/doctype.html

You may also want to use XHTML5 text elements listed here...

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#usage-summary

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where I found this so I can't give proper credit but I hope it helps as a starting point.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>UNTITLED</title>
</head>
<body>


<!-- Sample Content to Plugin to Template -->
<h1>CSS Basic Elements</h1>

<p>The purpose of this HTML is to help determine what default settings are with CSS and to make sure that all possible HTML Elements are included in this HTML so as to not miss any possible Elements when designing a site.</p>

<hr />

<h1 id="headings">Headings</h1>

<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<h4>Heading 4</h4>
<h5>Heading 5</h5>
<h6>Heading 6</h6>

<small><a href="#wrapper">[top]</a></small>
<hr />


<h1 id="paragraph">Paragraph</h1>

<img style="width:250px;height:125px;float:right" src="images/css_gods_language.png" alt="CSS | God's Language" />
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="#" title="test link">test link</a> adipiscing elit. Nullam dignissim convallis est. Quisque aliquam. Donec faucibus. Nunc iaculis suscipit dui. Nam sit amet sem. Aliquam libero nisi, imperdiet at, tincidunt nec, gravida vehicula, nisl. Praesent mattis, massa quis luctus fermentum, turpis mi volutpat justo, eu volutpat enim diam eget metus. Maecenas ornare tortor. Donec sed tellus eget sapien fringilla nonummy. Mauris a ante. Suspendisse quam sem, consequat at, commodo vitae, feugiat in, nunc. Morbi imperdiet augue quis tellus.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <em>emphasis</em> consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nullam dignissim convallis est. Quisque aliquam. Donec faucibus. Nunc iaculis suscipit dui. Nam sit amet sem. Aliquam libero nisi, imperdiet at, tincidunt nec, gravida vehicula, nisl. Praesent mattis, massa quis luctus fermentum, turpis mi volutpat justo, eu volutpat enim diam eget metus. Maecenas ornare tortor. Donec sed tellus eget sapien fringilla nonummy. Mauris a ante. Suspendisse quam sem, consequat at, commodo vitae, feugiat in, nunc. Morbi imperdiet augue quis tellus.</p>

<small><a href="#wrapper">[top]</a></small>
<hr />

<h1 id="list_types">List Types</h1>

<h3>Definition List</h3>
<dl>
  <dt>Definition List Title</dt>
  <dd>This is a definition list division.</dd>
</dl>

<h3>Ordered List</h3>
<ol>
  <li>List Item 1</li>
  <li>List Item 2</li>
  <li>List Item 3</li>
</ol>

<h3>Unordered List</h3>
<ul>
  <li>List Item 1</li>
  <li>List Item 2</li>
  <li>List Item 3</li>
</ul>

<small><a href="#wrapper">[top]</a></small>
<hr />

<h1 id="form_elements">Fieldsets, Legends, and Form Elements</h1>

<fieldset>
  <legend>Legend</legend>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nullam dignissim convallis est. Quisque aliquam. Donec faucibus. Nunc iaculis suscipit dui. Nam sit amet sem. Aliquam libero nisi, imperdiet at, tincidunt nec, gravida vehicula, nisl. Praesent mattis, massa quis luctus fermentum, turpis mi volutpat justo, eu volutpat enim diam eget metus.</p>

  <form>
    <h2>Form Element</h2>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nullam dignissim convallis est. Quisque aliquam. Donec faucibus. Nunc iaculis suscipit dui.</p>

    <p><label for="text_field">Text Field:</label><br />
    <input type="text" id="text_field" /></p>

    <p><label for="text_area">Text Area:</label><br />
    <textarea id="text_area"></textarea></p>

    <p><label for="select_element">Select Element:</label><br />
      <select name="select_element">
      <optgroup label="Option Group 1">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="Option Group 2">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
      </optgroup>
    </select></p>

    <p><label for="radio_buttons">Radio Buttons:</label><br />
      <input type="radio" class="radio" name="radio_button" value="radio_1" /> Radio 1<br/>
        <input type="radio" class="radio" name="radio_button" value="radio_2" /> Radio 2<br/>
        <input type="radio" class="radio" name="radio_button" value="radio_3" /> Radio 3<br/>
    </p>

    <p><label for="checkboxes">Checkboxes:</label><br />
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkboxes" value="check_1" /> Radio 1<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkboxes" value="check_2" /> Radio 2<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkboxes" value="check_3" /> Radio 3<br/>
    </p>

    <p><label for="password">Password:</label><br />
      <input type="password" class="password" name="password" />
    </p>

    <p><label for="file">File Input:</label><br />
      <input type="file" class="file" name="file" />
    </p>


    <p><input class="button" type="reset" value="Clear" /> <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>



  </form>

</fieldset>

<small><a href="#wrapper">[top]</a></small>
<hr />

<h1 id="tables">Tables</h1>

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <th>Table Header 1</th><th>Table Header 2</th><th>Table Header 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Division 1</td><td>Division 2</td><td>Division 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="even">
    <td>Division 1</td><td>Division 2</td><td>Division 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Division 1</td><td>Division 2</td><td>Division 3</td>
  </tr>

</table>

<small><a href="#wrapper">[top]</a></small>
<hr />

<h1 id="misc">Misc Stuff - abbr, acronym, pre, code, sub, sup, etc.</h1>

<p>Lorem <sup>superscript</sup> dolor <sub>subscript</sub> amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nullam dignissim convallis est. Quisque aliquam. <cite>cite</cite>. Nunc iaculis suscipit dui. Nam sit amet sem. Aliquam libero nisi, imperdiet at, tincidunt nec, gravida vehicula, nisl. Praesent mattis, massa quis luctus fermentum, turpis mi volutpat justo, eu volutpat enim diam eget metus. Maecenas ornare tortor. Donec sed tellus eget sapien fringilla nonummy. <acronym title="National Basketball Association">NBA</acronym> Mauris a ante. Suspendisse quam sem, consequat at, commodo vitae, feugiat in, nunc. Morbi imperdiet augue quis tellus.  <abbr title="Avenue">AVE</abbr></p>

<pre><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nullam dignissim convallis est. Quisque aliquam. Donec faucibus. Nunc iaculis suscipit dui. Nam sit amet sem. Aliquam libero nisi, imperdiet at, tincidunt nec, gravida vehicula, nisl. Praesent mattis, massa quis luctus fermentum, turpis mi volutpat justo, eu volutpat enim diam eget metus. Maecenas ornare tortor. Donec sed tellus eget sapien fringilla nonummy. <acronym title="National Basketball Association">NBA</acronym> Mauris a ante. Suspendisse quam sem, consequat at, commodo vitae, feugiat in, nunc. Morbi imperdiet augue quis tellus.  <abbr title="Avenue">AVE</abbr></p></pre>

<blockquote>
  "This stylesheet is going to help so freaking much." <br />-Blockquote
</blockquote>

<small><a href="#wrapper">[top]</a></small>
<!-- End of Sample Content -->


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, something like this, but some elements are absent, I guess I should add them. Anyway what it is called? This sample?

Comment: Found it http://smashingmultimedia.sarah-neuber.de/about/css-basic-elements

Comment: 13 errors, 6 warning(s).